# how to setup a build step in teamcity to run a standalone python script

Tags: python-3.x, teamcity

I am trying to set up a build step in teamcity to run a python script using command line and I have given command executables to be the script name and command parameters I am not sure what to put. please help in setting the build step

Answer (score 2):

Two options spring to mind for running a Python script from a teamcity build configuration:

**VCS Root**: You will need your python script to exist in your source repository so you can retrieve this via the vcs root.

**Python Path**: You may need to set this if you want to use a specific version of python.

```
PYTHONPATH=/apps/python/2.7.3
export PATH=${PATH}:${PYTHONPATH}/bin
alias python=${PYTHONPATH}/bin/python2.7
```

**Opt 1**: select the Command Line runner. In the Custom script script content box:

```
/path/to/python
```

Then, the remainder of the command in the parameters field:

```
python_script_name.py any param_one param_two ...
```

**Opt 2**: Install the [python runner plugin](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixipOA28_XAhXE0hoKHac1CQUQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplugins.jetbrains.com%2Fplugin%2F9042-python-runner&usg=AOvVaw0iIyCIuL_W2feWjmz0iCtl) for TeamCity. Though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: using command line the error thrown is not being handled and the script fails but on idle it runs successfully. also i tried to use Python Runner but its not able to run the script.. i dont know what should be the settings

Comment: Hi Sayali, what is the error you are seeing when using the command line runner? Have you set PYTHONPATH and updated your PATH?

Comment: i want to use the python runner.. command line runner when I use I don't know whether it has run the script successfully or not? also it gives exit code 0 but still I don't know the outcome.

Comment: as per your advice I have installed python runner.. not able to use it

Comment: Hi @sayali, I have updated the above, the script name actually belongs in the parameter field. Your script won't output anything to the log if you don't have stdout; print will output to stdout.